# ResourceExhaustedError :OOM when allocating tensor with shape []

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, word-sense-disambiguation

```
def RNN(X, weights, biases):
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])
    X_in = tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in']
    X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)

    outputs = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2]))    # states is the last outputs
    results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
    del outputs,final_state,lstm_cell,init_state,X,X_in
    return results

def while_loop(s,e,step):
    while s+batch_size<ran:
        batch_id=file_id[s:e]
        batch_col=label_matrix[s:e]                                             

        batch_label = csc_matrix((data, (batch_row, batch_col)), shape=(batch_size, n_classes))
        batch_label = batch_label.toarray()
        batch_xs1=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix,batch_id)
        batch_xs=sess.run(batch_xs1)
        del batch_xs1
        sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                        y: batch_label})

        print(step,':',sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_label}),sess.run(cost,feed_dict={x: batch_xs,y: batch_label}))
        if step!=0 and step % 20 == 0:
            save_path = saver.save(sess, './model/lstm_classification.ckpt',write_meta_graph=False)
            print('Save to path', save_path)

        step += 1
        s+=batch_size
        e+=batch_size
        del batch_label,batch_xs,batch_id,batch_col
        print(hp.heap())
        print(hp.heap().more)
```

This is my code.It keeps going this mistake 'ResourceExhaustedError:OOM when allocating tensor with shape'
I used guppy.Then got this.[result of guppy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi9NH.png)

Why the variable of tensorflow take so much space.

Comment: See [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow#t=201702280511203392708) for dealing with memory leaks in TensorFlow. In particular, the call to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, ...)` inside a Python loop suggests that `embedding_matrix` is being converted to a TensorFlow constant and stored in the graph multiple times, which is probably the source of your memory leak.

Comment: You advised using tf.graph.finalize() .But after that I can not use tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, ...) .So what shold I do?

Comment: You could define `batch_xs1 = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, batch_id_placeholder)` outside the while loop (where `batch_id_placeholder` would be a `tf.placeholder()` of the appropriate type and shape), then compute `batch_xs` as `batch_xs = sess.run(batch_xs1, feed_dict={batch_id_placeholder: batch_id})`.

Comment: Thanks!It worded.One more question,in this code,I saved the model.When I restore it,do I need to run init = tf.initialize_all_variables() again?Before the restore step or after?

Comment: Assuming the checkpoint from which you restored has all of the variables, you shouldn't need to run the op returned by `tf.initialize_all_variables()` (now called `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in TF 1.0).

Comment: I see, I didn't save all the variables.But should I run the  initialize step before restore step or after?If I run the initialize step after restore ,will it recover the restored variables?Furthermoe,I have 10000+ classes.when training,the accuracy is about only 1%.Could you tell me the reason?It is because of the training data?

Comment: You should initialize before restoring—otherwise the initializers will overwrite the values that you've restored. I'm not sure what the cause of the poor accuracy is though... that might be more of a question for [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by this line in the training loop:

```
while s + batch_size < ran:
    # ...
    batch_xs1 = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, batch_id)
```

Calling the [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) function adds nodes to the TensorFlow graph, and—because these are never garbage collected—doing so in a loop causes a memory leak.

The actual cause of the memory leak is probably the `embedding_matrix` NumPy array in the argument to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`. TensorFlow tries to be helpful and convert all NumPy arrays in the arguments to a function into [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) nodes in the TensorFlow graph. However, in a loop, this will end up with multiple separate copies of the `embedding_matrix` copied into TensorFlow and then onto scarce GPU memory.

The simplest solution is to move the `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` call outside the training loop. For example:

```
def while_loop(s,e,step):
  batch_id_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
  batch_xs1 = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, batch_id_placeholder)

  while s+batch_size<ran:
    batch_id=file_id[s:e]
    batch_col=label_matrix[s:e]                                             

    batch_label = csc_matrix((data, (batch_row, batch_col)), shape=(batch_size, n_classes))
    batch_label = batch_label.toarray()

    batch_xs=sess.run(batch_xs1, feed_dict={batch_id_placeholder: batch_id})
```

Comment: Hi,  I am also having OOM issues during training of NN, but mine is a GCN and does not have that embedding function.  However, I think my issue might also lie in some functions because I can proceed one round with no error, while the second round would definitely bring some OOM error.  Would appreciate it if you can take a look at my post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178061/how-to-avoid-getting-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape420128-512-in-loop)!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem with TF + Keras and previously with Darknet with yolo v3.
My dataset contained very large images for the memory of my two GTX 1050s.
I had to resize the images to be smaller.
On average, a 1024x1024 image needs 6GB per GPU.