# How to solve "OOM when allocating tensor with shape[XXX]" in tensorflow (when training a GCN)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, graph, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So...  I have checked a few posts on this issue (there should be many that I haven't checked but I think it's reasonable to seek help with a question now), but I haven't found any solution that might suit my situation.

This OOM error message always emerge (with no single exception) in the second round of a whatever-fold training loop, and when re-running the training code again after a first run.  So this might be an issue related to this post: [A previous stackoverflow question for OOM linked with tf.nn.embedding_lookup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499592/resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape), but I am not sure which function my issue lies in.

My NN is a GCN with two graph convolutional layers, and I am running the code on a server with several 10 GB Nvidia P102-100 GPUs.  Have set batch_size to 1 but nothing has changed.  Also am using Jupyter Notebook rather than running python scripts with command because in command line I cannot even run one round...  Btw does anyone know why some code can run without problem on Jupyter while popping OOM in command line?  It seems a bit strange to me.

UPDATE:  After replacing Flatten() with GlobalMaxPool(), the error disappeared and I can run the code smoothly.  However, if I further add one GC layer, the error would come in the first round.  Thus, I guess the core issue is still there...

UPDATE2:  Tried to replace `tf.Tensor` with `tf.SparseTensor`.  Successful but of no use.  Also tried to set up the mirrored strategy as mentioned in ML_Engine's answer, but it looks like one of the GPU is occupied most highly and OOM still came out.  Perhaps it's kind of "data parallel" and cannot solve my problem since I have set `batch_size` to 1?

**Code** (adapted from [GCNG](https://github.com/xiaoyeye/GCNG)):

```
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
import tensorflow as tf
#from spektral.datasets import mnist
from spektral.layers import GraphConv
from spektral.layers.ops import sp_matrix_to_sp_tensor
from spektral.utils import normalized_laplacian
from keras.utils import plot_model
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import gc

l2_reg = 5e-7  # Regularization rate for l2
learning_rate = 1*1e-6  # Learning rate for SGD
batch_size = 1  # Batch size
epochs = 1 # Number of training epochs
es_patience = 50  # Patience fot early stopping

# DATA IMPORTING & PREPROCESSING OMITTED

# this part of adjacency matrix calculation is not important...
fltr = self_connection_normalized_adjacency(adj)
test = fltr.toarray()
t = tf.convert_to_tensor(test)
A_in = Input(tensor=t)
del fltr, test, t
gc.collect()


# Here comes the issue.

for test_indel in range(1,11):

    # SEVERAL LINES OMITTED (get X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test)
    
    # Build model
    N = X_train.shape[-2]  # Number of nodes in the graphs
    F = X_train.shape[-1]  # Node features dimensionality
    n_out = y_train.shape[-1]  # Dimension of the target
    X_in = Input(shape=(N, F))
    graph_conv = GraphConv(32,activation='elu',kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),use_bias=True)([X_in, A_in])
    graph_conv = GraphConv(32,activation='elu',kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg),use_bias=True)([graph_conv, A_in])
    flatten = Flatten()(graph_conv)
    fc = Dense(512, activation='relu')(flatten)
    output = Dense(n_out, activation='sigmoid')(fc)
    model = Model(inputs=[X_in, A_in], outputs=output)
    optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()

    save_dir = current_path+'/'+str(test_indel)+'_self_connection_Ycv_LR_as_nega_rg_5-7_lr_1-6_e'+str(epochs)
    if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
        os.makedirs(save_dir)
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=es_patience, verbose=0, mode='auto')
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=save_dir + '/weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    checkpoint2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=save_dir + '/weights.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)
    callbacks = [checkpoint2, early_stopping]

    # Train model
    validation_data = (X_val, y_val)
    print('batch size = '+str(batch_size))
    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size,validation_data=validation_data,epochs=epochs,callbacks=callbacks)

    # Prediction and write-file code omitted
    del X_in, X_data_train,Y_data_train,gene_pair_index_train,count_setx_train,X_data_test, Y_data_test,gene_pair_index_test,trainX_index,validation_index,train_index, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test, validation_data, graph_conv, flatten, fc, output, model, optimizer, history 
    gc.collect()
```

**Model Summary**:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 13129, 2)     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)            (13129, 13129)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
graph_conv_1 (GraphConv)        (None, 13129, 32)    96          input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
graph_conv_2 (GraphConv)        (None, 13129, 32)    1056        graph_conv_1[0][0]               
                                                                 input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 420128)       0           graph_conv_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 512)          215106048   flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            513         dense_1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 215,107,713
Trainable params: 215,107,713
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch size = 1
```

**Error message** (Please note that this message never comes during the first round after a Restart-and-Clear-Output):

```
Train on 2953 samples, validate on 739 samples
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-943385df49dc> in <module>()
     62     mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
     63     print("current mem " + str(round(mem.percent))+'%')
---> 64     history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size,validation_data=validation_data,epochs=epochs,callbacks=callbacks)
     65     mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
     66     print("current mem " + str(round(mem.percent))+'%')

/public/workspace/miniconda3/envs/ST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

/public/workspace/miniconda3/envs/ST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    194                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    195 
--> 196                 outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
    197                 outs = to_list(outs)
    198                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

/public/workspace/miniconda3/envs/ST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

/public/workspace/miniconda3/envs/ST/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[420128,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training_1/Adam/mul_23}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[metrics_1/acc/Identity/_323]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[420128,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training_1/Adam/mul_23}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Comment: 215 million parameters is huge. Google BERT is normally around 100m parameters and that requires some serious computational power to train from scratch. Try reducing your dense nodes from 512. Try with a small number say 32 and increase from there until you find the balance

Comment: @ML_Engine Thanks for your comment!  I was honestly shocked by the number of parameters initially, too.  The number of nodes (number of cells, 13129) is kind of fixed and difficult to change because adequate resolution is needed for the biological data I am processing, while the whole region is also needed.  But I can in fact process one round (for a fixed `test_indel`) with `batch_size` as high as 32...  That's why I think the problem might be some duplication of data generated by functions inside loops, instead of the parameters.

Comment: Can generate final results by manually setting the `test_indel` from 1 to 10 and run (restart-and-clear-output in between).  Am thinking about replacing `Flatten()` with `GlobalMaxPool()`, since the latter seems to be more commonly used in modern CNNs, and will take less parameters to deal with.

Comment: Ah I've just seen you have access to multiple GPUs. Perhaps try using a distributed strategy to make sure tensorflow is making use of all of your GPUs. I'll add some code to an answer to demonstrate

Comment: Did you come to a clear understanding of this issue? Find a generalisable solution?

Comment: @Simon Nah, I am doing everything with PyTorch now.  I remember things getting better with Torch.  OOM might've still popped out anyways in the project my question was referring to a year ago though, and I assumed it's due to the size of input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of distributed strategies in tensorflow to make sure that your multi-GPU set up is being used appropriately:

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    for test_indel in range(1,11):
         <etc>
```

See the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy)

Mirrored strategy is used for synchronous distributed training across multiple GPUs on a single server, which sounds like the setup you're using. There's also a more intuitive explanation [in this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-a-neural-network-on-multi-gpu-with-tensorflow-42fa5f51b8af).

Also, you could try making use of [mixed precision](http://tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision) which should free up memory significantly by altering the float type of the parameters in the model.

Comment: Thanks!  Would test this method today or tomorrow.

Comment: You're welcome. Please 'accept' my answer if it helped!

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I cannot accept it currently because it turns out I still have some related errors to fix. I tried mirrored strategy but OOM is still popping out. It looks like TF is utilizing other available GPUs (the only error messages are about `XLA_GPU`s, sample message: `INFO:tensorflow:Device is available but not used by distribute strategy: /device:XLA_GPU:1`). Not sure why this is happening... I checked GPU memory usage when running the code on jupyter notebook with `nvidia-smi`, but it looks like only `GPU:1` is being used (memory usage: `10056 MiB / 10156 MiB`)

Comment: (Continuing last comment) To be more precise, after using mirrorer_strategy, one of my GPUs (GPU:1) has its most memory being occupied, while the other 5 GPUs, though being used by the process, still have ~99% memory available (memory usage: 147 MiB / 10156 MiB).  However, normally Jupyter Notebook will utilize multiple available GPUs for work (exactly one all and the others just a small fraction of memory occupied), so I am not sure if this shows mirror strategy working or it's not working at all.

Comment: What is the output of `print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))` ? Try adding this to the top of your script

Comment: Output: `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:2', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:3', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:4', device_type='GPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:5', device_type='GPU')]`.  Have put it in the front but OOM still pops out.  Is TF1 bad at dealing with memory issues?  I can try to migrate to TF2 or PyTorch if they could deal with large dataset (large data) better

Comment: I would try migrating first

Comment: Decided to try pytorch instead.